# App FCs when started itself.LogCat and other files attached

Tags: android, geolocation, nullpointerexception, android-manifest, android-activity

This is a location based app.The MainActivity.java is the first file to get executed,But the app Force Closes as soon as it is opened.LogCat included.
Please help.Hope to get the answer here.
**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.location.sensor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     LocationListener locationlistener;
     Location loc;
     PendingIntent pendint;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationlistener=new MyLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
            Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);
            //Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.jump);
            //btn.startAnimation(anim);
            TextView n= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.jump);
                        anim.setDuration(3000);
                        //v.startAnimation(anim);
                        TextView n= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                        EditText txt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
                        //Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.jump);
                        n.startAnimation(anim);
                        String s=txt.getText().toString();
                        n.setText(s);
                        n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icn);                    
                    }
                });

                EditText txt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
                //Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.jump);
                String s=txt.getText().toString();
                    //LocationManager lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    //LocationListener locationlistener=new MyLocationListener();
                    //lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 10, locationlistener);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(this,NotificationClass.class);
                    Bundle extras=new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("alarm", s);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    lm.addProximityAlert(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 8, -1, pendint);


    }

 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                loc.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enable GPS in Settings!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
             msg.arg1 = 1;
             handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }



        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

 }
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
         @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              if(msg.arg1 == 1){
                   if (!isFinishing()) { // Without this in certain cases application will show ANR
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled! Would you like to enable it?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                  Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                  startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
                              }
                         });
                         builder.setNegativeButton("Do nothing", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   dialog.cancel();
                              }
                         });
                         AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                         alert.show();
                   }
               }

           }
    };
 }
```

**NotificationClass.java**

```
package com.location.sensor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NotificationClass extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView txtview=new TextView(this);
        txtview.setText("Hey,Im Sorry");
        setContentView(txtview);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        String data=getIntent().getExtras().getString("alarm").toString();
        Bundle enter= getIntent().getExtras();
        if(enter.getBoolean("KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.notif);
        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_pendint);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        tv.setText(data);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(0);

            }
        });
        }
    }
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case 0:

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.excl_mark)
                .setTitle("Do you want to Cancel?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.location.sensor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/gps1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".NotificationClass"
            android:label="YOU ARE IN PROXIMITY AREA!!!"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.locationsensor.notif"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
    08-01 17:51:17.546: D/AndroidRuntime(483): Shutting down VM
08-01 17:51:17.546: W/dalvikvm(483): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.location.sensor/com.location.sensor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.location.sensor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  ... 11 more
08-01 17:56:17.656: I/Process(483): Sending signal. PID: 483 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger and step through the on create method? There are a number of possible places of failure there. One is the button code, do you have a button named btn_OK in the layout_main.xml file? Use the debugger to see what is null.

Comment: Yes,i have a 'btn_OK'. It was working fine until i created the 'private' variables in the 'Activity' class

Comment: What is line 68 of MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your 'loc' variable is NOT instantiated, which is why you are getting a 'NULL Pointer" exception (which will cause a FC of your app).

These 2 lines in your stack trace point me to that:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 17:51:17.566: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.location.sensor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)

Comment: still not working.I instantiated the loc with null outside and inside the onCreate() method. It still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `findViewById()` in your `btn.setOnClickListener()`. You are calling the `findViewById()` in the anonymous inner class for your `OnClickListener` class. So Android will look for a method `findViewById()` in your `OnClickListener`.

Just initialize the `Views` in your `onCreate()`.

Or you could create a variable called `private Context context` and then in your `onCreate()` make it `this`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     context = this;
     //... your code
}
```

and call your `context.findViewById()` in the `btn.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: It will work, but it might not have been the only problem you're experiencing. Your error seems to be the `Location` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things broken at the end of your MainActivity.onCreate():

```
intent.putExtras(extras);
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
lm.addProximityAlert(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 8, -1, pendint);
```

I assume that you want to pass the PendingIntent to `addProximityAlert()`. However, you don't do anything with the PendingIntent that is returned from `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. Then you pass `pendint` to `addProximityAlert()` and it is for sure **null**. You probably wanted to do something like:

```
pendint = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
lm.addProximityAlert(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 8, -1, pendint);
```

Also, you call `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` on the variable `loc`, but that variable was also never set to anything so it is for sure **null**.

Fix those things and see how far you get.

Comment: Okay. But i have initialised loc in onLocationUpdate() of the MyLocationListener() method.

Comment: `onLocationChanged()` will not be called between the time you call `requestLocationUpdates()` and the time you try to use it. In fact, there is no guarantee that `onLocationChanged()` will ever be called. You need to understand that requesting location updates doesn't **synchronously** cause `onLocationChanged() to be called. It just requests that you be notified of location changes in the future.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks :) i will change my code accordingly and update here.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something quite similar to this. I had the code working perfectly when I was working only with the onLocationChanged. The problem started when I was using the onLocationChanged along with the addProximityAlert.

After adding the Proximity Alert the onLocationChanged never got called and the initialized objects in the onLocationChanged method started giving me a null pointer.

I am not too sure on this but I might like to also bring this question on the table that whether there is a problem with the onLocationChanged being called along with the addProximityAlert? Or maybe there is something extra that we need to do to have both of them working together?

Comment: No the problem was with the Location object in the Activity class. its still null when I try to access it. better is the pass the location got directly from onLocationChanged and pass it to a method to perform your operation which you want. It worked for me.